# Executing query with where, whereHas in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5, eloquent

I'm building a small application in `Laravel 5.5` where I'm querying something like this:

```
$models = Contact::where('first_name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search_input.'%')
    ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', '%'. $request->search_input.'%')
    ->orWhereHas('company', function ($q) use($request) {
        $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%'.$request->search_input.'%');
    })
    ->whereHas('company', function ($query) {
        $query->where('type', '=', 'Research');
    })
    ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
    ->take(50)
    ->get();
```

The idea behind is, I want to search the list of contact with `first_name`, `last_name` and their `company name` (which is a relational data) with the `search_input` and filter them with `type = Research` in the `company list`, I mean only those `contact` should appear which is having `company` `type` as `research`.

But currently I'm getting all the list of contacts without filtering it with type. Help me out with this. Thanks.

Comment: Change your second `whereHas` to `orWhereHas`, or put the first two where's in a subquery/closure. Mixing ANDs and ORs  is a bad thing unless done properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use where closure:

```
Contact::where(function($q) use($request) {
        $q->where('first_name', 'like', '%' . $request->search_input . '%')
          ->orWhere('last_name', 'like', '%' . $request->search_input . '%')
          ->orWhereHas('company', function ($q) use($request) {
              $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->search_input . '%');
        });
    })
    ->whereHas('company', function ($query) {
        $query->where('type', 'Research');
    })
    ->latest()
    ->take(50)
    ->get();
```